# Address of a Global Variable in the Heap Address Range

Tags: c, heap-memory, mplayer, memory-layout

I was debugging the `MPlayer-1.3.0` source code, and I saw a global variable whose address (returned by `GDB` or even simple printing) was in the range for the heap allocations, instead of the data section. I checked the heap range using `procfs`.

```
555555554000-555555834000 r-xp 00000000 08:12 798876  /usr/bin/mplayer
555555a33000-555555b25000 r--p 002df000 08:12 798876  /usr/bin/mplayer
555555b25000-555555b2b000 rw-p 003d1000 08:12 798876  /usr/bin/mplayer
555555b2b000-555556479000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0       [heap]
7fffc3fff000-7fffc8000000 rw-s 00000000 00:16 1932    /dev/shm/pulse-shm-3887887751
```

The variable definition is `int verbose = 0;`, at `line 40` of `mp_msg.c` and the address is `0x555555b3bbb0`, which is in the `[heap]` mapping. I even checked some variable definitions before and after it:

```
int mp_msg_levels[MSGT_MAX]; // verbose level of this module. initialized to -2
int mp_msg_level_all = MSGL_STATUS;
int verbose = 0;
int mp_msg_color = 0;
int mp_msg_module = 0;
```

Of these, only `mp_msg_level_all` is located in the data section. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your question is "why is `int verbose = 0;` allocated to `[heap]` memory mapping according to `/proc/self/maps` ?", the answer is that

1. the whole `[heap]` notion is really a relic of the long forgotten past, and
2. the traditional `[heap]` starts immediately after the `.bss`, and they usually share the same mapping, so there is *nothing* to be surprised about here.

Expanding on point 1 a bit, in the traditional UNIX memory model of old (before threads and `mmap` became a thing), on processors where stack grows down, top half of the memory was reserved for the kernel space, stack started at the highest end of user memory, the program `.text` itself started at address 0, with `.data` and `.bss` immediately following, and then heap (the `brk` / `sbrk` kind) immediately after. This allowed heap to grow to higher addresses, and gave combined heap+stack the maximum available memory.

That model doesn't work well at all in the presence of threads, shared libraries and memory mapped files, and has been largely abandoned by modern `malloc` implementations, which rarely bother with `sbrk` at all. Instead they just `mmap` the memory they need (and any such memory will not show up in `[heap]` that you see in `procfs`).

P.S.

- The idea of mapping zero page into the process space has long been abandoned as it only leads to bugs. This is why `.text` starts at higher addresses on all modern UNIXen.
- Giving the kernel half of available address space is also quite wasteful, and 32-bit Linux started to give the kernel much less space. On 64-bit systems running out of address space is no longer an issue.

**Update:**

> So you mean that [heap] contains both .bss and part of heap. So, the only way to determine if an address is inside the heap is to trace malloc(),free(),... calls?

I don't think I explained this well.

The *notion* that there is a single region in the process space called "heap" is obsolete. A modern `malloc` implementation is likely to have multiple thread-specific arenas, obtained from the system via `mmap`, and a heap-allocated object can be in any one of them.

You can't easily say "oh, this address 0x568901234 looks like heap", because it could be anything.

> What is the standard way to determine the address ranges for virtual memory areas (e.g., .text, heap and .bss) of a process in Linux, if procfs output is obsolete?

Here again, you are trying to explain memory layout in terms that are somewhat obsolete: there *isn't* a single `.text` or `.bss` in most processes, because each shared library will have its own (in addition to that of the main executable). And there are many *additional* sections as well (`.tls`, `.plt`, `.got`, etc.) *And* sections aren't even *required* at runtime at all -- ELF (at runtime) needs only segments, and doesn't care about sections.

Comment: Thanks @employed-russian. So you mean that `[heap]` contains both `.bss` and part of `heap`. So, the only way to determine if an address is inside the heap is to trace `malloc(),free(),...` calls? Am I right?

Comment: `One more question:` What is the standard way to determine the address ranges for virtual memory areas (e.g., `.text`, `heap` and `.bss`) of a process in `Linux`, if `procfs` output is obsolete?

Comment: The benefit of *experience* over plain *knowledge* is evident in your answer suggesting you didn't just fall off the turnip truck yesterday `:)`

Comment: Thanks again. Do you know a method for capturing only dynamic data accesses (not `.bss` accesses) in the range corresponding to `[heap]`?

Answer (score 1):

`mp_msg_level_all` is in the data section because it is initialized to a non-zero value. The rest is initialized to 0, and as such belong to the **`bss`** section.

Why the linker decided to put `bss` into the apparently heap address range we may only wonder.